# Defeating the helicopter in Split Second

Tags: xbox-360, split-second

I'm having some trouble in the episode where you're supposed to defeat the helicopter.  I do pretty well in the episodes where you're supposed to avoid the helicopter fire.  I must be missing a power play or something because I haven't been able to finish higher than seventh. How do I defeat the helicopter?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found this on gamefaqs for the ps3 version which is the same as the xbox version.

> For this event you will need to build
>   up your bar by drifting as well as
>   avoiding missiles. Once you have done
>   that use your Level 2 Power Play
>   (Circle) button to deflect the
>   missiles back at the helicopter.
>   Destroy the Helicopter as fast as you
>   can to reach the target time you need
>   to get 1st.

Comment: You live longer using level 1 power plays, but since this is a timed event not always useful.  Level 2 power plays are the only way to do enough damage quickly enough.